# pip install ssl python

Tags: python, ssl, pip

```
Collecting ssl
  Using cached ssl-1.16.tar.gz (33 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\ljikshdfo1324opi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LJIKSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-f5753j2j\\ssl_f205297257114d91a81bc61187e23786\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LJIKSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-f5753j2j\\ssl_f205297257114d91a81bc61187e23786\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-pip-egg-info-kqr23xvb'
       cwd: C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-f5753j2j\ssl_f205297257114d91a81bc61187e23786\
  Complete output (6 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-f5753j2j\ssl_f205297257114d91a81bc61187e23786\setup.py", line 33
      print 'looking for', f
                        ^
  SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/21/f469c9923235f8c36d5fd5334ed11e2681abad7e0032c5aba964dcaf9bbb/ssl-1.16.tar.gz#sha256=ac21156fee6aee9eb8d765bbb16f5f49492d81ff4b22f7b8fc001d2251120930 (from https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached ssl-1.15.tar.gz (32 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\ljikshdfo1324opi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LJIKSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-f5753j2j\\ssl_0d019aa65cfd4bcc9d0cab59a8b008de\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LJIKSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-f5753j2j\\ssl_0d019aa65cfd4bcc9d0cab59a8b008de\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-pip-egg-info-7db5urec'
       cwd: C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-f5753j2j\ssl_0d019aa65cfd4bcc9d0cab59a8b008de\
  Complete output (6 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\LJIKSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-f5753j2j\ssl_0d019aa65cfd4bcc9d0cab59a8b008de\setup.py", line 74
      print 'looking for', f
                        ^
  SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/c2/846a19d1572ec6cb8ac438d58a898de8926d32e13f0355cdf4ab00864b5f/ssl-1.15.tar.gz#sha256=1266302ce62c4b60c7ca0e1d3d104ba11d2749e5881d8ac4f006cf9a0446d589 (from https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: 1.15, 1.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ssl
```

Что делать? без ssl я не смогу работать со скриптом, urllib требует фикса(то есть ssl)
а сам ssl не устанавливается. Обновлял питон с 3.6 по 3.10
pip тоже обновлял

Comment: Это какой-то не тот ssl. Судя по `print 'looking for', f` это что-то вообще для Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно устанавливать пакет `ssl` https://pypi.org/project/ssl/
Он предназначен для Пайтона второй версии.

В третьей версии модуль `ssl` встроен и поставляется практически со всеми реализациями.

Попробуйте выполнить команду в консоли `python3 -c 'import ssl'`

Если она завершится без ошибок, значит у вас модуль `ssl` вкомпилирован прямо в `python.exe`.

Если же будет сообщение

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ssl'
```

значит надо установить другой пайтон, в котором `ssl` есть.